# jQuery fallback for this css3 animation on ie9

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am using animate.css for css3 animations, but ie9 and older not support css3 animations.

I use a pulse animation in all the buttons of this page: http://www.codetocode-developments.com/demos/battle/index.html

and I have been trying to make a jQuery fallback (with modernizr):

```
if(!Modernizr.cssanimations) {
    $('.btn').hover(
        function() {
            $(this).animate({
                padding:'15px 30px'
              }, 500)
        },
        function() {
            $(this).animate({
                padding:'10px 20px'
              }, 500)
        }
    );
}
```

I did not succeed. Somebody knows how to do this effect width jQuery?

Comment: Are you looking for something like http://jquery.malsup.com/hoverpulse/ ?

Comment: Yes, but it will be better if I can do it without a plugin. Thanks, I will use this if I don't find any other way.

Comment: is not there a method for scale elements with jquery?

Comment: If you want to achieve the same animation as on your page, you must animate your buttons width, height, margin-left, margin-top properties simultaneously, so the user will have the effect of proportionate increase of the button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this example [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/tovic/tuSdh/)

Credits go to the author of the script.

**HTML**

```
<img src="http://healingaia.com/img/nb-petal-detox.png" />
<img src="http://healingaia.com/img/nb-petal-detox.png" />
<img src="http://healingaia.com/img/nb-petal-detox.png" />
<img src="http://healingaia.com/img/nb-petal-detox.png" />
```

**CSS**

```
body {overflow:hidden;}

img {
 display:block;
 margin:10px auto 0px;
 position:relative;    
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$(function() {
    $('img').hover(function() {
        $(this).stop().animate({
            width:'472px',
            height:'246px',
            marginTop:'-118px',
            bottom:'-59px',
        }, 1000, "easeOutBack");
    }, function() {
        $(this).stop().animate({
            width:'236px',
            height:'123px',
            marginTop:'0px',
            bottom:'0px'
        }, 700, "easeOutBounce");
    });
});
```